# Side by side images (Centering subfloats and changing font)

Tags: captions, fontsize, subfloats

I have the following images produced by the following code:

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cXX@{}}
%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[Node 3 - Therapy Group 1 (443 patients)]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{3e3}} 
   & \subfloat[ Node 4 - Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 1 (116 patients)  ]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{3e4}}\\
\subfloat[Node 5 - Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 2 (39 patients)]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{1e5}} 
   & \subfloat[Node 6 - Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 3 (16 patients)]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{3e6}}\\
\subfloat[Node 7 -Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 34 (8 patients)]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{3e7}} 
\end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
```

How can I
1) Make the caption font smaller
2) get the whole image centered to the middle of the page
3) get the last figure (e) centered with the other above it
4) get them even apart so that the caption would fit in 1 line

Comment: ???? you have 3 column tabularx but you only use a single cell, the first column of the first row, in which you have a tabular, why have the tabularx at all?

Comment: is there a simpler way to do it? I am new to latex

Comment: most of the lines in there are not doing anything at all so just deleting them all would be simpler, I'll post an example in a bit

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be the `floatrow` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption,floatrow,graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\DeclareCaptionSubType[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=colon}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{%
  font=footnotesize,labelformat=brace,labelsep=space,labelfont=bf}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{capposition=bottom,heightadjust=all,valign=t}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \ffigbox{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}
      \ffigbox
      {\caption{Node 3 - Therapy Group 1 (443 patients)}}%
      {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}%

      \ffigbox
      {\caption{Node 4 - Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 1
          (116 patients)}}% 
      {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}

    \begin{subfloatrow}
      \ffigbox
      {\caption{Node 5 - Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 2
          (39 patients)}}%
      {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}%

      \ffigbox
      {\caption{Node 6 - Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 3
          (16 patients)}}%
      {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}\par  
    \begin{subfloatrow}
      \ffigbox
      {\caption{Node 7 -Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 34 (8
          patients)}}%
      {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}}
  {\caption{Fitting for subsample 1}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Please always post full documents, in particular showing packages used, my initial guess was `subfloats` package but I guess it was `subfig`. the `tabular` and especially the `tabularx` are doing nothing useful here, they can simply be deleted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[Node 3 - Therapy Group 1 (443 patients)]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[ Node 4 - Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 1 (116 patients)  ]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}

\subfloat[Node 5 - Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 2 (39 patients)]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[Node 6 - Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 3 (16 patients)]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}

\subfloat[Node 7 -Therapy Group 0 \& Initial State Group 34 (8 patients)]{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}} 

\end{figure}
\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

If you need to change the font simply use `\small` at the start of the `figure` although the font would have to be much smaller to make the captions fit on one line.

[image]

Comment: the font is still bound to under the picture only though. I wish it can go outside more

Comment: @user1930901 well the whole point of the package seems to be to set the caption to the width of the content, however you can make that content wider by eg `\subfloat[Node 3 - Therapy Group 1 (443 patients)]{\hspace{.1in}\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}\hspace{.1in}}%` although you can not add much more than that .2in as, as shown in the image above there is not that much space (assuming you are using usletter,again, you did not say) to get two 5.5in images side by side

Comment: thanks! also is there a way to start labelling from (c) for instance instead of (a) ?